# GWT client-side: java.util or com.google.gwt.dev.util?

Tags: java, gwt, collections, client-side

**On a GWT client-side, is it better to use java.util, or com.google.gwt.dev.util?**  Does it matter? What is the biggest reason for com.google.gwt.dev.util existing?

For example, would it be better to use **java.util.HashMap, or com.google.gwt.dev.util.collections.HashMap?**  Is it com.google.gwt.dev.util.collections.HashMap, as its JavaDoc says it's memory-efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refrain from using any classes from gwt-dev library. gwt-dev.jar is not supposed to be present in your runtime class path. It is only required for running the application in development mode.

[GWT: Difference between gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810582/gwt-difference-between-gwt-user-jar-and-gwt-dev-jar)